# How does the following method works

Tags: java

Hi I found the following code for comparing a set of fingerprints:

```
public float compare(Fingerprint fingerprint) {
    float result = 0f;

    HashMap<String, Integer> fingerprintMeasurements = fingerprint.getMeasurements();
    TreeSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>();
    keys.addAll(mMeasurements.keySet());
    keys.addAll(fingerprintMeasurements.keySet());

    for (String key : keys) {
        int value = 0;
        Integer fValue = fingerprintMeasurements.get(key);
        Integer mValue = mMeasurements.get(key);
        value = (fValue == null) ? -119 : (int) fValue;
        value -= (mValue == null) ? -119 : (int) mValue;
        result += value * value;
    }

    //result = FloatMath.sqrt(result); // squared euclidean distance is enough, this is not needed

    return result;
}

    /** compares the fingerprint to a set of fingerprints and returns the fingerprint with the smallest euclidean distance to it */
    public Fingerprint getClosestMatch(ArrayList<Fingerprint> fingerprints) {
        //long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Fingerprint closest = null;
        float bestScore = -1;

        if(fingerprints != null) {
            for(Fingerprint fingerprint : fingerprints) {
                float score = compare(fingerprint);
                if(bestScore == -1 || bestScore > score) {
                    bestScore = score;
                    closest = fingerprint;
                }
            }           
        }

        //time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        //Log.d("time", "\n\n\n\n\n\ncalculation location took " + time + " milliseconds.");
        return closest;
    }
```

1)
how does the loop works.
It is my understanding that we scan all the values stored in the keys reference of the TreeSet

the qestion is mainly on the lines

```
value = (fValue == null) ? -119 : (int) fValue;
value -= (mValue == null) ? -119 : (int) mValue;
```

what is the question mark doing on those lines of code?

2) why do we need the minus one in the follwing line of code to stract the best fingerprint parameter

```
if(bestScore == -1 || bestScore > score) {
```

3) is there way to see the assignment of the values in eclipse (for debugging purposes)?

Comment: Do a google search of the ternary operator. For that matter, doing a google search of "java question mark" would have given you results. You shouldn't just copy-paste code you find on the internet and hope for the best. You have to understand what it's doing first. And are you asking about debugging in eclipse? If so, there's another google keyword for you.

Comment: 1) Ternary operator. 2) No idea, it's an implementation choice that we weren't included on. 3) Yes, you can execute your program in debug mode and use breakpoints (and the Watch) to view variables their values at intermediate points during execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  That is the Java [Ternary Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).  It is equivalent shorthand for an if/else statement with assignment.

2) bestScore is being initialized to an application-specific invalid value to indicate that it has not been assigned a valid value yet.  In this case, when the first time through the loop, it will be assigned the first score value.

3)  Yes, you can step through your app in eclipse. There are many [Tutorials on the web](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

`?:` is a ternary statement. It's the shorthand equivalent to an `if` statement. It would set the value of a variable if the expression is true or false.

**Example:** `variable = expression ? value-if-true : value-if-false`

Set Eclipse in debug mode, and you can step through the logic. This will help you decipher what is what. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html).